# A meta riddle for?

Tags: wordplay

*Edit: this riddle is intended to be spoken, not read.  There are no word clues.*

"Wherefore came this plank?" asked Dr. Watson.
"We must first determine the exact whereabouts of it's origin." replied Sherlock Holmes.
"Well, just a moment ago I sat here, minding my manners staring out the window, when I felt drowsy and nearly fell asleep. I awoke quickly as my head began to topple over, feeling as if I was missing something and that is when I saw this flat piece of wood upon the floor where none was before." said Watson, scratching his head.
"What were you doing staring out the window?" inquired Holmes.
"Oh, I really don't recall. I had finished my tea and have no other duties this day therefore I was staring out the window."
"Hmm..." pondered Holmes. "Were you dreaming?"
"I don't recall..."
"Thinking?"
"Not sure..."
"Waiting for me!"
"Yes, yes, perhaps..." Watson said flustered. "I don't think I had a plan at all."
"What you have here is a fantastic case of an ineptitude to comprehend modern metaphors. *Abire in animo.*" replied Holmes stoically pointing his pipe at the deceptive lumber. "We must get you a new hobby".

What is Holmes *(and this riddle)* referring to?

Comment: Watson is as thick as two short planks clearly

Comment: Note that "wherefore" doesn't mean "where", but actually means something closer to "why".

Comment: @gentlepurplerain thanks for clarifying!  I adjusted the wording.

Comment: Is the answer that he got board... bored*?
I hope that's not the intended punswer... answer*

Comment: As long as we're correcting words and whatnot, "it's" as in "it's origin" should be "its" because "it's" is short for "it is" or "it has" and is not a possessive form.

Comment: I do not see a "spoken" tag for riddles.  It wasn't intended to be read and linguistically analyzed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deduce the answer comes from a combination of:

> *abire in animo* - Latin roughly for out of the mind

and

> "Wherefore came this plank?" and "...I saw this flat piece of wood on the floor where none was before." as well as the reference to deceptive lumber which points to a play on words for board / bored.

which would point to Dr. Watson having a case of:

> being "Bored out of his mind".

Comment: rot13: 
Gur dhrfgvba "Jurersber pnzr guvf cynax?" naq gur urnq gbccyvat "srryvat nf vs V jnf zvffvat fbzrguvat" vf n qverpg nyyhfvba gb n "obneq bhg bs uvf zvaq".  Guvf vf yrff chmmyr naq zber cha, naq gung'f abg n tbbq guvat.

Comment: rot13: Fubhyq V abg unir tvira na nafjre gura?

Comment: Why would you think that?  Supplement yours if you like, but it seems fitting in its essentials

Comment: I am sorry, I must have misunderstood your comment. I will edit my post to give more clarity on my answer.